# Science fiction novel with a sentient (and morally conscious) planet. Possibly called "Rogue" or "Rogue Planet"

Tags: story-identification, books

In the early 1960's, I read an SF book that I think was titled "Rogue" or "Rogue Planet", although that could be wrong.  The story involved a planet that somehow inserted itself into orbit near earth.  Society then was quite decadent, except of course for the hero.  The planet was sentient and also 'moral'.  The hero eventually had to escape earth and flew to this planet, which he found to be an Eden.  The planet had created a barrier to other ships, and eventually this man and a female (possibly created by the planet) were able to start a new life together.  It's not 'great literature', but it is a story I'd like to read again.

Comment: We need more details. When did you read it? What were the characters? What was the plot? Was it smutty?

Comment: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_title&OPERATOR_1=starts_with&TERM_1=Rogue&CONJUNCTION_1=AND&USE_2=title_title&OPERATOR_2=exact&TERM_2=&CONJUNCTION_2=AND&USE_3=title_title&OPERATOR_3=exact&TERM_3=&ORDERBY=title_copyright&START=0&TYPE=Title covers a wide variety of "Rogue" titles.

Comment: About 50 years ago there was "The Wanderer", a 1964 science fiction novel by Fritz Leiber. It won the 1965 Hugo Award for Best Novel.

Answer (score 3):

About 50 years ago could be E.C. Tubb's *[Rogue Planet](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2757)* from 1976. Summary from [here](https://www.risingshadow.net/library/book/5047-rogue-planet:):

> Many and strange have been the adventures of Moon Base Alpha and its crew since the atomic waste pits on the dark side of the Moon exploded and sent them careering out of Earth orbit, deep into unexplored space.
>
> Always they have managed to overcome their perils and continue their strange Odyssey. Now, at last they seem to have reached the end of the road, as caught in a weird cone of force emanating from a sentient planet, they find themselves ageing at an incredible rate and powerless to break free.

The title is not entirely accurate, as they don't encounter a planet, but rather "[a giant green pulsating brain that they call Omphalos](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7703953-rogue-planet)" on the planet.

Comment: Does it fit the description about a sentient planet?

Comment: Sort of. Added details

Comment: "the atomic waste pits on the dark side of the Moon exploded and sent them careering out of Earth orbit" ?! I hope he got some $$ from Space: 1999!

Comment: @OrganicMarble: It was also released as *Space 1999: Rogue Planet*. :-D

Comment: Ah. Indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The book you are looking for is *[Rogue in Space](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/21520373-rogue-in-space)* by Fredric Brown. The book about a sentient asteroid that arrives in the solar system's asteroid belt after countless aeons of wandering interstellar space.  He collects the asteroids to himself to become a planet.  The hero, his girlfriend and some others, escaping from a decadent earth, are allowed to land and start a new civilization.

Comment: *Rogue in Space* has a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_in_Space). Reviewed by P. Schuyler Miller in [*ASF* November 1957](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v60n03_1957-11_Gorgon776#page/n147/mode/2up). "Extensively rewritten" fix-up of two novelettes, ["Gateway to Darkness"](https://archive.org/details/Super_Science_Stories_v06n01_1949-11) and ["Gateway to Glory"](https://archive.org/details/Amazing_Stories_v24n10_1950-10) (links to the Internet Archive).

Comment: P. Schuyler Miller did not like it but I thought it was very good. Personal taste I guess.